# Setting test cookie in generic view in Django

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-generic-views

I want to set a test cookie in my CreateView and be able to get a test result in `form_valid` function (after sending a form).

Where should I put the code responsible for setting the cookie?

```
self.request.session.set_test_cookie()
```

I tried to override `get_form_kwargs` and put it there, but it didn't work.

My code:

```
class MyView(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if not self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            pass
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs for `test_cookie_worked`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.test_cookie_worked

"Due to the way cookies work, you’ll have to call set_test_cookie() on a previous, separate page request."

Therefore I would suggest to `set_test_cookie` in the `get` method of the view:

```
class MyView(CreateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request.session.set_test_cookie()
        super(MyView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if not self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            pass
        else:
            pass
```